# Implementing a PHP compatible memcache client for node.js

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

I'm trying to implement another pure javascript memcache client for node.js.
The question is that I have to get keys which were set by PHP Memcache class from multipule memcache server, but I can't figure out how PHP hashes those keys.

I have looked for the Memcache class manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php

the "memcache.hash_function" is "crc32", but I still have no idea how to determine which server to set from a crc32 hash.

Is there some docs or references?
Thanks in advence.

Comment: Why not use redis and upgrade the PHP code to use redis? Alternatively just rewrite the PHP code in node. Writing a pure javascript memcache client is just as painful for significantly less gain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information will be housed in PECL: http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache

To find out the details you will most likely need to review the [source of the extension](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/memcache/).

Answer (score 1):

I used http://search.npmjs.org/#/memcache via npm. Works fine across node.js and php(with the 'memcached' mod not 'memcache').

The documentation is sparse though.You can use the code below to get started.

```
var memcache = require('memcache');

var client = new memcache.Client(11211, '127.0.0.1');

client.connect();

client.get('aaa', function(error, result){

    console.log(result);
    // all of the callbacks have two arguments.
    // 'result' may contain things which aren't great, but
    // aren't really errors, like 'NOT_STORED'

});
```